# Beautiful soup doesn't scrape the data from the "next" pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape airbnb data using BeautifulSoup and Pandas. I checked a lot of tutorials and found the one I followed. The step in which the soup should scrape the data from the next page is not working, out of 15 pages, it scrapes only the first 2 or 3 pages or sometimes even none (even if the URLs of the pages are correct).

**I cannot seem to understand why this happens and how to solve it. Can someone help out?**

```
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import time

url = 'https://www.airbnb.it/s/Italy/homes?checkin=2021-08-01&checkout=2021-08-02'

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    return soup

def get_listings(soup):
    result = []
    result.extend(soup.find_all("div", {"class": "_8ssblpx"}))
    return result

def get_listing_title(listing):
    for l in listing:
        try:
            return str(l.find('div', {'class': '_1tanv1h'}).text)
        except:
            return None

def get_listing_subtitle(listing):
    for l in listing:
        try:
            return str(l.find('span', {'class': '_1whrsux9'}).text)
        except:
            return None

def get_listing_info(listing):
    for l in listing:
        try:
            return str(l.find_all('div', {'class': '_3c0zz1'})[0].text.lower())
        except:
            return None

def find_next_page(page):
    base_url = "https://www.airbnb.it"
    try:
        nextpage = base_url + get_page(url).find_all("div", attrs={"class": "_jro6t0"})[0].find("a", attrs={'class':'_za9j7e'})['href']
    except:
        nextpage = None
    return nextpage

title = []
subtitle = []
info = []

while url is not None:
    soup = get_page(url)
    listings = get_listings(soup)
    for l in listings:
        title.append(get_listing_title(l))
        subtitle.append(get_listing_subtitle(l))
        info.append(get_listing_info(l))
    time.sleep(5)
    url = find_next_page(soup)
    print(url)

airbnb_data = pd.DataFrame(data = {'title': title,
                          'subtitle': subtitle,
                          'info': info})
airbnb_data
```

Comment: If I had to take a guess, you're probably being rate limited if this is happening inconsistently. What status code are you getting on the request when this fails?

Comment: I don't get an error, the function ```find_next_page``` returns "None" after first few pages so, accordingly, I get the final result with only a part of the listings.